# How to use excel file data in an ios app?

Tags: ios, c++builder, rad-studio, tlistview

I'm new to Rad Studio so I may be missing something, but I am trying to create an iOS app that just displays a list of data.  I currently have an iOS app with a tListView that gets populated by a ClientDataSet, which is populated with data that I hard-coded into an xml file that's on my PC.  I want to be able to fill my ListView with the data that is in an excel file instead of xml file so that when I need to add an item I can just add it in the excel file on my PC and rebuild the project. Is this possible? The only way I have found to access excel file data is TADO Connection, but it seems you can not use it on iOS applications. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend against using Excel files for this purpose.
There are several reasons for that:

1. Excel files are not designed to be sources of data for automated processing. These are electronic spreadsheets designed to be used by humans. Formats like XML, CSV and JSON work much, much better as data sources for programs.
2. Excel file format is incredibly complex and requires that you ship a specialized library inside your app. This severely increases the binary size of your app and the download time, makes it start up slower and use more RAM.
3. Decoding an Excel document is a CPU heavy task, i.e. your app will drain the battery much more than it should.
4. Excel file stores much more information in addition to your raw data that is absolutely not needed for the data consumer such as a mobile app.
5. It's very easy to accidentally break the data contract with the Excel file. Imagine that the app expects some value in the cell A1. If I insert a new column in the very beginning and make it hidden, the file will still look the same at first glance, but the consumer will not read it correctly.

If your data is fundamentally a hierarchy (a tree) of various objects with different sets attributes, use JSON or XML.

If your data is rather a set of similar objects (a table), use CSV.

Whether you choose JSON, XML or CSV, parsing them will be a much easier task for a mobile app.

If you need a convenient GUI to manually update a file like that, consider using Visual Studio Code with plugins. Or, in case of CSV, you can actually use Excel (just save the final result back to .csv rather than to .xlsx).

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation! I have decided to use XML as the data source for my program.

Comment: I have come across another problem now that maybe you can help me out with? I have created the xml file to fill my dataset and it works when I compile my application for windows because the program directly references the path of the xml file, which is stored on the PC.  I want to be able to make this work with iOS, so I emailed the xml file to myself and downloaded it in the files app under On My iPhone.  Now I need to know the path of that file in order to link it to my program that reads and displays the data.  (1/2)

Comment: I spent a lot of time googling this yesterday and it seems I need to change the entitlement keys in order to allow read access to files in the iPhone? But I can't find how to do that as it looks like the key "com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-only" is only available for macOS. Is this even possible in iOS? I know the app can't access files outside the sandbox, but surely there must be a way? Thanks in advance for any insight you may be able to provide! (2/2)

Comment: This is th ebest thing I found... https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/providing_access_to_directories but I guess I am still confused because I am using rad studio c++ builder, not swift in x-code and don't know how to translate that example into a c++ version that would work for me. (3/2)

Comment: If you want the file to be available as a part of the app, you better to ship the file inside the app bundle rather than have the user select it. Unfortunately I don't know how to do that with Rad Studio since I've never used it. In Xcode, it's enough to just include a file into the target and it will be copied into the bundle during compilation. I'd suggest to create a new question so that someone could help.

Comment: Yeah I know how to do it that way but I was hoping to be able to access the file without shipping it in the app bundle. I'll create a new question, thank you for your help!